# Error Message: "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST"

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

when i access to endpoint this http://localhost/newsapp_api/public/api/register,this message is showed
"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST".
[look to the link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of6Jx.png)

but when i tried register new user and entered data(name,email,password) for user by postman program
this message is showed "message": "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$map".
and it doesn't give json data.
[look to the link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH5W9.png)

**api.php**

```
Route::POST('register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@store');
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'  => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password'  => 'required'
        ]);
        $user = new User();
        // $user->name = $request->get( 'name' );
        // $user->email = $request->get( 'email' );
        // $user->password = Hash::make( $request->get( 'password' ) );
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = Hash::make( $request->password );
        $user->save();
        return new UserResource( $user );
    }
```

**UserResource.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class UserResource extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using form data .

Comment: which form data you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, try to use Params instead of body to submit data to the end point

Comment: please,write the code how will become

Comment: If you use the postman extension throw it away and use the postman main application.

Comment: why?what's problem? what's different?i use postman  application/json in header tab

Comment: If you're trying to enter that URL in your browser, your browser will send a GET method.

Comment: it's okey,now i understood why message get me this message
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem when you enter your endpoint in the browser, the browser will send GET method to your endpoint. Since your endpoint only accepts POST method, it throws an error.

The second problem is you extends UserResource with ResourceCollection so UserResource expects a collection. However you pass a User object which is not a collection to UserResource.

I think you meant to create a UserResource as just a resource which extends JsonResource

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#introduction

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works successfully

Comment: how can i make that?

Comment: click at up arrow icon for upvote, click at check icon for accepting an answer.

Comment: Ok, but I 've this issue "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."